# How to check which line of a Python script is being executed?

Tags: python, stack-trace

I've got a Python script which is running on a Linux server for hours, crunching some numbers for me. I'd like to check its progress, so I'd like to see what line is being executed right now. If that was a C or C++ program then I would just attach to the process with `gdb -p <pid>` and examine the stacktrace with `where`. Of course, I can do the same with the Python interpreter process, but I can't see the Python script's line in the stacktrace.

So, how can I find out which line of the Python script is being executed currently?

Comment: Just found this thread and decided to save a link to it in a comment, as it seems relevant: 'Pyringe: Debugger capable of attaching to and injecting into Python processes' https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7496261

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a signal handler to the Python script that sends this information to the terminal, or to a file, then hit ^C in the terminal to send the signal to the process.

```
import signal

def print_linenum(signum, frame):
    print "Currently at line", frame.f_lineno

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, print_linenum)
```

You could also use some other signal and use the `kill` command to send the signal, if you need ^C to be able to interrupt the script, or set a `signal.alarm()` to print the information periodically, e.g. once a second.

You could print out other things from the stack frame if you like; there's a lot there. See the attributes of `frame` objects [in this table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#types-and-members).

Comment: Thanks, that's nice. Any idea what to do if the running script doesn't have this signal handler yet?

Comment: I suppose you could dig around using `gdb` to find the current stack frame and dig out its `f_lineno` but it seems like more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll wait a bit to see if someone has an idea what to do without the signal handler, if not I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I wish bash's "set -x" was there in python.