# Is it possible to see which line is currently being executed in VS Code Debuggging Mode?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to debug some code (big directory with several modules) which gets stuck after some minutes and I would like to know in which function (or which line of the file) this happens. I am aware of this solution but am looking for some alternative to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459298/how-to-check-which-line-of-a-python-script-is-being-executed) solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you click _F5_ to debug code in VS Code, will it not stay at the problematic code line and display related information? Have you ever tried to break at the line of code you want to view?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It breaks when I click F6. I just realized you can check which line was executed by looking at the call stack. I didn't see it before your comment. So thank you! :)

Comment: @SahraGhalebikesabi could you provide a screenshot